# Linux Update Manager not installing updates

Tags: linux, linux-mint, updates

Having problems updating using Update Manager i.e - when I click on 'install updates', when timer stops, screen stays the same - nothing gets installed.

I'm running LM 17.2 (mintUpdate 4.9.3)
currently using the following (default) mirrors:

```
'Main': http://packages.linuxmint.com
'Base': http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I've already tried:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install synaptic  
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install mint-meta-mate mintupdate mintinstall synaptic
```

Depending on the package, I can sometimes install using terminal, but I'd rather use Update Manager to install my updates

Anymore info reqd? Can anyone help?

Comment: Regarding update here have a look at this [upgrade to Linux Mint 17.2](http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2871) whether this assist you with some idea.

Comment: I have already upgraded to Linux Mint 17.2. I looked through post you offered, but found nothing that has helped or hadn't already tried.

Comment: I have the same issue in LMDE 2 Betsy, same mintUpdate 4.9.3